# OWASP & Angular - Still getting "Absence of Anti-CSRF Tokens" alert even after implementing CSRF Protection

Tags: angular, csrf, angular9, owasp

I'm trying to validate my app using the AWASP ZAP software.

I spent the last 2 days implementing CSRF protection using Angular 9 + Core 3.1. It seems to be working fine, however, when I start the tests I got the "Absence of Anti-CSRF Tokens" alert from 30 different lines. Those alerts are coming from the angular compiled file (vendor-es2015.js) and in some cases, from commented lines.

Below is a screenshot with an example.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After long research and tests, my conclusion is: that it's a false-positive alert. No way to workaround the scanner or fix this "error" on the Angular code, because it's not really Angular's fault.

Same issue related here: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/6089